# Is there a way to check if first Character is alphabet using express-validator?

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

case 'user_name': {
return [
check(
'content.data.userName',
'username need atleast one alphabet'
)
// .matches('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])')
.exists()
.trim()
.bail()
.isLength({ min: 6 })
.withMessage('User Name must be atleast have 6 characters')
.isLowercase()
.withMessage('Must be all small letters')

```js
case 'user_name': {
            return [
                check(
                    'content.data.userName',
                    'username need atleast one alphabet'
                )
                    // .matches('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])')
                    .exists()
                    .trim()
                    .bail()
                    .isLength({ min: 6 })
                    .withMessage('User Name must be atleast have 6 characters')
                    .isLowercase()
                    .withMessage('Must be all small letters')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
This regular expression helps you to check the first character is alphabet or not.
```

`^[a-zA-Z][\w\s-]+`

First character can be only a-zA-Z

Not to allow special characters other than "space" and "hyphen(-)"

```
.matches(/^[a-zA-Z][\w\s-]+/)
```

Hope it works, Thank you!